# Using fread and fwrite in one stream at the same time caused a problem

Tags: c

This program want to read from a file. the content in the file is the string "Hello, world". then judge each character of the string to see if the character greater than or equal to the const character 'e', if the character meet the condition, than change the character to its previous character in the alphabetical order (eg. 'b' change to 'a', 'e' change to 'd').  Finally, output the changed file content to the screen.

The question is how do the fwrite and fread work? why can't I get rid off the variable pos2 to simplify the expression. If anyone can help, thanks a lot!

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()

{
    FILE *fp;
    char s[20];
    char t[20];
    char transfer;
    int i;
    int pos; // storing the position of the file before reading from the file 
    int pos1; // check the position of the file
    int pos2; // storing the position of the file after reading from the file
#pragma region create a file named "Hello", write "Hello, world" into the file, close it
    if ((fp = fopen("Hello", "wb") )== NULL)
    {
        printf("can't open file\n");
        exit(0);
    }
    strcpy(s, "Hello, world");
    fwrite(s, sizeof(char)*20, 1, fp);
    fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_SET);
    fclose(fp);
#pragma endregion create a file named "Hello", write "Hello, world" into the file, close it
#pragma region read from the file named "Hello", deal with its current, write the change into the file.
    if ((fp = fopen("Hello", "rb+")) == NULL )
    {
            printf("can't open file\n");
            exit(1);
    }
    i = 0;
    while(i < 20) 
    {
            // 提问，该处为何不能利用fwrite的自动定位免去注释掉的语句行（即使用了pos2的语句行）。
            // Here is the problem. since the fread and fwrite function can move the position of the 
            // file, I think I can get rid off the following commented two sentences with the 
            // variable pos2 in it
            pos = ftell(fp);     // storing the position before reading from file
            fread(&transfer, sizeof(char), 1, fp); // the position of the file moved to the next char
            // pos2 = ftell(fp);  // storing the position after reading from file
            pos1 = ftell(fp);
            if (transfer >= 'e')  // if the character greater or equal to 'e' minus 1.
            {
                transfer -= 1;
            }
            fseek(fp, pos, SEEK_SET); // back to the position where the character is read to change the char
            fwrite(&transfer, sizeof(char), 1, fp);// the position of the file moved to the next char
            // fseek(fp, pos2, SEEK_SET); // 
            pos1 = ftell(fp);
            i++;
    }
    fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_SET);
    fclose(fp);
#pragma endregion read from the file named "Hello", deal with its current, write the change into the file.
#pragma region read from the file named "Hello", output the changed string
    if((fp = fopen("Hello", "rb")) == NULL)
    {
            printf("Can't open file\n");
            exit(2);
    }
    fread(t, sizeof(char)*20, 1, fp);
    printf("The output is: %s \n", t); 
// the right output is (the two sentences above with pos2 in it is commented) ：
// The output is: Hdkkn,vnqkd
// the wrong output is (the two sentences above with pos2 in it isn't commented): 
// The output is: Hddddddddddddddddddd烫烫烫烫Hello, world
    fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_SET);
    fclose(fp);
#pragma endregion  read from the file named "Hello", output the changed string
    system("pause");
}
```

Comment: You're originally writing 20 bytes to the file, but the `s` variable is only initialized with 13 characters. the other 7 are garbage - something which should be considered. As writing also advances the file position, you need the marks where you store pos2 (but you could just have done `fseek(fp, pos1, SEEK_SET)` instead of `fseek(fp, pos2, SEEK_SET) `  )

Comment: Yes you are right. I just want people can read the code easily. the use of the variable pos1 is to show the file position. the pos2 is used to storing the position of the file after read from the file in which way I can return to the position. as the result turns out I think there maybe one pointer to advance the file when reading from the file and there is another pointer to advance it when writing into the file. I am not experienced, I statically allocated the length of the string to store the content of the file.

Comment: @Vicky Thanks for formatting. Since it is the first time that I use this website, I will do it better here after.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't actually get the point why you are trying to comment in/out the 2 lines. Because nothing changes whether you comment them in or comment them out. You have already got rid of pos2 in your code (which is what you are asking).

So if you use the following code for your while loop

```
pos = ftell(fp);     // storing the position before reading from file
fread(&transfer, sizeof(char), 1, fp); 
pos1 = ftell(fp);
if (transfer >= 'e')  // if the character greater or equal to 'e' minus 1.
{
    transfer -= 1;
}
fseek(fp, pos, SEEK_SET);
fwrite(&transfer, sizeof(char), 1, fp);
i++;
```

then you get "The output is: Hdkkn,vnqkd" which is the expected result.

You could also take each line from the file to an array and make operations on it then write it back to the file. By this way, it could be more generic and you don't have to use magic numbers like "20".

EDIT:

I use gcc 4.5.2 on my linux platform. I don't want to comment on other platforms but as I mentioned before you could take the line to a buffer and then after operation you could write it back. You could try to replace the following code with your while loop:

```
char line[20] = {0};

fread(line, sizeof(char), 20, fp);

for(i = 0; i < strlen(line); i++)
{
    if(line[i] >= 'e')
        line[i] -= 1;
}

fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_SET);
fwrite(line, sizeof(char), strlen(line), fp);
```

By this way you could get rid of many variables. It is your choice.

Comment: Thanks for help. In my compiler(vs 2008) if I don't use the variable pos2 as you did above, I got the result is Hddddddddddddddddddd烫烫烫烫Hello, world. then I changed a compiler (gcc in MinGW ). Than I got a result like this:Hddddddddddddddddddd   Hello, world. Finally I want to try it out in linux (cc compiler). I got the right answer (without using the variable pos2): Hdkkn,vnqkd. I don't know if it is a bug in the compiler. I wonder what's the compiler you use?

Comment: You could also debug the program where it actually fails on your windows platform. And please share it I wonder why.

Comment: your change of the code works. But I just wonder why my code without the variable `pos2` couldn't work, when I debug the code,something happens: the variable `transfer` first get a value 'H', since 'H' less than 'e' nothing changed. Then the `transfer` get a value 'e' equal to 'e' then the value of transfer changed to 'd'. in the following iterations, the value of `transfer` before minus operation is always 'e' then it changed to 'd' after the operation. there must be something wrong in the manipulation of the file position. but I can't figure it out.

Comment: Have you checked the values of pos after each fwrite and fread? Are they changed in the way you expected? Can you share them as well?

Comment: OK. Found the solution. It seems like windows does not flushes the changes you have done. Whereas linux does. That's the problem. Thus, your changes does not effect the file and wrong output is taken. In order to get around this just put `fflush(fp)` at the end of your while loop. That will make the trick.

Comment: Thanks for help！You are right. it is the problem of flush. Since I don't know the `fflush()` function. I should learn more about the I/O of the files. Here is the reference  of `int fflush ( FILE * stream )`[link](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/fflush/). It's my first question on `stackoverflow.com`, It's a fantastic experience! helps are appreciated.