# fwrite in c going in an infinite loop

Tags: c, fwrite, fread

I am trying to update records in a .DAT file using fread and fwrite but somehow the loop runs infinitely.  My code is:

```
FILE *fq;
Employee eme;
long int recsize_eme;
recsize_eme=sizeof(eme);

fq=fopen("EME.DAT","rb+");
if(fq==NULL)
{
    fq=fopen( "EME.DAT","wb+");
    if(fq==NULL)
    {
        printf("Can't Open File");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
}

rewind(fq);
while(fread(&eme,recsize_eme,1,fq)==1)
{
    if (compare_date(eme.pre_pay_date)==0 && compare_date(eme.pol_end_date)!=0)
    {
        int date[3];
        int n;
        n = sscanf(eme.pre_pay_date, "%d/%d/%d", &date[0], &date[1], &date[2]);
        if(date[1]!=12)
        {
            date[1]++;
        }
        else
        {
            date[1]=1;
            date[2]++;
        }

        snprintf(eme.pre_pay_date, sizeof(eme.pre_pay_date), "%d/%d/%d", date[0], date[1], date[2]);
        printf( eme.pre_pay_date );
        if (eme.pre_status!=0)
        {
            eme.pre_payment = eme.premium;
        }
        else
        {
            eme.pre_payment = eme.premium + eme.pre_payment;
        }
        printf( "%f %f\n",eme.premium,eme.pre_payment );
        fseek(fq,-recsize_eme,SEEK_CUR);
        fwrite(&eme,recsize_eme,sizeof(eme)/recsize_eme,fq);
    }
}
fclose(fp);
```

the function if updating the values correctly but when writing it keeps on printing the values infinitely.  **eme** is an attribute of struct Employee which i have declared.

Comment: Probably checking the return value of fseek() and fwrite() can help

Comment: why do you need fseek()?

Comment: Try writing in different file. reading and writing in the same file would lead to problems. It might be that the EOF is not encountered if you are writing in the file from which you are reading!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not saying on which platform you are, but I could reproduce your issue on MS-Windows with MingW gcc 4.6.2. The issue is that [Windows does not flush the buffers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7316920/using-fread-and-fwrite-in-one-stream-at-the-same-time-caused-a-problem) after an `fwrite()`. Add

```
fflush(fq);
```

after the `fwrite()` call to solve this.

See also my [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) at https://github.com/afester/StackOverflow/tree/master/updateRecord